# filter value of properties of an array when properties are not the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

```
const myArray = [ { status: null }, { rooms: 2 }, { bathrooms: 3 }, { vaccum: null } ]
```

Here is the array and I want to filter the values of null and exclude the object from array no matter what the property is.

Since the properties are not the same I can't go:

```
const filteredArray = myArray.filter(property => {
    property.status == null
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by filtering based on the values in the object, and wether or not any of them are `null` or not

```js
const myArray = [{
  status: null
}, {
  rooms: 2
}, {
  bathrooms: 3
}, {
  vaccum: null
}];

let result = myArray.filter( o => {
  return !Object.values(o).includes(null)
});

console.log(result)
```

`Object.values` is not supported in all browsers, but can easily be replaced by a simple loop for older browsers

```js
const myArray = [{
  status: null
}, {
  rooms: 2
}, {
  bathrooms: 3
}, {
  vaccum: null
}];

var result = myArray.filter( o => {
  for (key in o) {
   if ( o[key] === null ) return false;
  }
  return true
});

console.log(result)
```